# Button pointing to another function after Hiding one panel and showing another

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the a situation here .

**My motive** : Hiding one panel and showing another.

**Whats Working** :Layout wise , my app is behaving like i want it to .

**The Problem** : After the I hide one panel and show another , the button in this panel (process button) is still pointing to the function binded with "OUT" button .

**Steps to be followed** :

1. Run the program .
2. Press "Process" button. Then press "Out" Button .
3. U will see old panel come back. Again press "Process" button .
4. Observe that the button is running the function binded with the "OUT" Button.

Here is the complete program :

```
import wx


class Panels(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(500,-1))

                #Font
        #__init__(self, pointSize, family, style, weight, underline=False, face=EmptyString, encoding=FONTENCODING_DEFAULT) 
        self.font1 = wx.Font(12, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC,wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, underline = True )
        self.font2 = wx.Font(10, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL,wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, underline = False )
        self.font3 = wx.Font(10, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC,wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, underline = True )

        favicon = wx.Icon('icon.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        wx.Frame.SetIcon(self, favicon)

        list_choice = ['ALL','UnSeen','DRAFT']

        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

#Launch panel Defined

        panel_launch = wx.Panel(self,-1,style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)



#Layout Defination

        hbox= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        lbl_Username = wx.StaticText(panel_launch,0, "Username:")
        lbl_Username.SetFont(self.font3) 
        self.txt_Username = wx.TextCtrl(panel_launch,0)#wx.Size(self,w,h)
        lbl_Password = wx.StaticText(panel_launch,0, "Password:")
        lbl_Password.SetFont(self.font3) 
        self.txt_Password = wx.TextCtrl(panel_launch,0,style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)

        btn_Process = wx.Button(panel_launch,0, "Process")

        hbox.Add(lbl_Username,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox.Add(self.txt_Username,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox.Add(lbl_Password,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox.Add(self.txt_Password,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox.Add(btn_Process,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        panel_launch.SetSizer(hbox)


#Menu section
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        pehla=wx.Menu()
        doosra=wx.Menu()
        teesra =wx.Menu()
        option_menu=wx.Menu()
        info=wx.Menu()

#Menu Items

        self.item1_1=pehla.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,"&Add Mail\tAlt-A","This is to add a mail account") #Sub-Items of First menu pull down list
        item1_2=pehla.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"&Quit\tAlt-Q","This will exit app") #The last comment will show on status bar when mouse is on that option
        item3_2=teesra.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,"A&bout\tAlt-B","About Section")


        menu_1=menubar.Append(pehla,'&File')    #Naming of Menu items
        menu_2=menubar.Append(doosra,'&Edit')
        menu_3=menubar.Append(teesra,'&Info')
        item2_1=option_menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,'Export File Location')
        doosra.AppendMenu(wx.ID_ANY,"&Options\tAlt-O",option_menu)
        self.item1_1.Enable(False)
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.vbox.Add(panel_launch,-1,wx.EXPAND,10)

        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)

        self.Layout()

        self.Centre()

        self.Show(True)

#Event Bindings

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSignIn,btn_Process)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnAddMail,self.item1_1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnFileExit,item1_2)



#+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-
#--------------------------Frame Related Function Zone--------------------------------------

    def OnSignIn(self,event):
        print "We are in default"

        mymail = self.txt_Username.GetValue()
        mypwd = self.txt_Password.GetValue()
        self.tstremove(event) #Hiding the old panel items
        panel_signedin = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        lbl_email = wx.StaticText(panel_signedin,0, "Email:")
        lbl_email.SetFont(self.font3) 
        txt_mymail = wx.StaticText(panel_signedin,0,mymail)
        txt_mymail.SetFont(self.font2)
        btn_OUT = wx.Button(panel_signedin,0, "OUT")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSignOut,btn_OUT)
        hbox3= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox3.Add(lbl_email,0,wx.ALL,10)
        hbox3.Add(txt_mymail,0,wx.ALL,10)
        hbox3.Add(btn_OUT,0,wx.ALL,10)
        panel_signedin.SetSizer(hbox3)
        self.vbox.Add(panel_signedin,-1,wx.EXPAND,10)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.Layout()
        self.item1_1.Enable(True) #Enable 'Add' menu item

    def OnSignOut(self,event):

        print "We are out"
        event.GetEventObject().GetParent().Hide()

        self.txt_Username.GetParent().Show(True)
        self.Layout()
        return


    def OnSignInNew(self,event):

        print "We are in New"

        self.item1_1.Enable(True)
        mymail1 = self.txt1_Username.GetValue()
        mypwd1 = self.txt_Password.GetValue()
        self.tstremove(event)
        panel_signedin1 = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        lbl_email1 = wx.StaticText(panel_signedin1,0, "Email:")
        lbl_email1.SetFont(self.font3) 
        txt_mymail1 = wx.StaticText(panel_signedin1,0,mymail1)
        txt_mymail1.SetFont(self.font2)
        btn1_OUT = wx.Button(panel_signedin1,0, "OUT")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSignOut,btn1_OUT)

        hbox31= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox31.Add(lbl_email1,0,wx.ALL,10)
        hbox31.Add(txt_mymail1,0,wx.ALL,10)
        hbox31.Add(btn1_OUT,0,wx.ALL,10)
        panel_signedin1.SetSizer(hbox31)
        self.vbox.Add(panel_signedin1,-1,wx.EXPAND,10)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.Layout()


    def tstremove(self,event):

        event.GetEventObject().GetParent().Hide()
        self.Layout()
        return

    def tstrecall(self,event):
        event.GetEventObject().GetParent().UnHide()
        self.Layout()
        return


    def OnAddMail(self,eventdef):
        self.item1_1.Enable(False)
        self.vbox.Add((-1,5))        
        panel_new = wx.Panel(self,0,style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        hbox1= wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        lbl1_Username = wx.StaticText(panel_new,-1, "Username:")
        lbl1_Username.SetFont(self.font3) 
        self.txt1_Username = wx.TextCtrl(panel_new,-1)#wx.Size(self,w,h)
        lbl1_Password = wx.StaticText(panel_new,-1, "Password:")
        lbl1_Password.SetFont(self.font3) 
        self.txt1_Password = wx.TextCtrl(panel_new,-1,style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)

        btn1_Process = wx.Button(panel_new,-1, "Process")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSignInNew,btn1_Process)

        hbox1.Add(lbl1_Username,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox1.Add(self.txt1_Username,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox1.Add(lbl1_Password,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox1.Add(self.txt1_Password,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        hbox1.Add(btn1_Process,0,wx.LEFT|wx.TOP,10)
        panel_new.SetSizer(hbox1)

        self.vbox.Add(panel_new,-1,wx.EXPAND,10)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.Layout()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSignInNew,btn1_Process)
        return

#+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-+-()-
#--------------------------Process Related Function Zone--------------------------------------

    def OnFileExit(self, event):
        """ File|Exit event """
        self.Close()




app = wx.App()
Panels(None, -1, 'Test')
app.MainLoop()
```

I just can't get, how one button is pointing to another function?
Is hiding and showing not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving BOTH buttons the same ID. Actually, you're giving almost ALL your widgets the same ID. You should NEVER do that. If you change the id parameter in all your widgets to wx.ID_ANY or just -1, you'll get randomly assigned ids and your program will work.

Comment: Oh.....Thanks Sir for the guidance...Will try it today.......Need to make a lot of changes in the program........Hope it does the job.....

Comment: Yahoooooooooooooo.............It worked........Im sorry could'nt stop myself from trying now itself.........I gave all the ids some unique numbers.....And it worked like magic....Thanks a lot Sir.....

Comment: Just an FYI: According to "wxPython in Action", you don't normally want to assign static ids yourself. That's why I recommended "-1" or wx.ID_ANY

Comment: Oh....Il keep that in mind......I guess in small apps , it is OK to give yr own IDs but yes , in big ones , one should never give static IDs because we might make a mistake of creating duplicate IDs which may clash....Thank you for the info Sir.........